# Guzzle not respecting HEAD request after 302 redirect

Tags: php, curl, http-headers, guzzle

I need to `HEAD` a file download URL to inspect the `ETag` in the response headers WITHOUT downloading the entire file. I'm doing this:

```php
$headers = $this->guzzle->head($url, ['debug' => true])->getHeaders();
```

But I'm noticing it downloading the entire file just to return the headers. After adding that `debug` option I can see from the output that it's doing a `HEAD` request to the URL and getting back a `302 Found` redirect to Amazon S3, and the subsequent request after Guzzle follows the redirect is a `GET`:

```
> HEAD /my-url HTTP/1.1
Host: dl.somecdn.com

< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Content-Length: 0
< Location: https://2-web-shpcd1.dl.somecdn.com/d786/200050/mf/2508250/13372192.pdf

> GET /d786/200050/mf/2508250/13372192.pdf
User-Agent: Laravel/#unknown GuzzleHttp/6.5.5 curl/7.74.0 PHP/8.1.15

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/octet-stream
< Content-Length: 516612308
< ETag: "8f7414fc764ae7ebb668dc8836c9539f-5"
< Server: AmazonS3
< X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront
< Via: 1.1 4eb35caa679bb95c591a03f41b151b8c.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
< X-Amz-Cf-Pop: YTO50-P1
< X-Amz-Cf-Id: LaI4vdjpcwfhhqb3OqTqt23Ooc4fLgb_PQJYnTlTPJQNvA2mGw_nww==
```

Because of that `GET` request after following the redirect, the entire file is being returned in the HTTP response and not just the headers, which is hugely wasteful as these files can be multiple GBs in size.

I found this Guzzle issue from back in 2018 which is similar, but it's dealing with 301 redirects and not 302s: https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/2046

Is there a way for me to solve this with 302 redirects?

Comment: Technically this is the correct behaviour. If it is permissible for the request to be anything other than a GET then the server should issue a 307 instead, which signals that the client should use the new URL with the _same_ method. 307/309 responses are not commonly known/used though. In the case of handling this client side, you'd need to set Guzzle/curl to _not_ follow the redirect, get the `Location:` header, and issue a new HEAD request.

Comment: Understood - thanks. I ended up dealing with this by doing as you suggested, recursively issuing HEAD requests manually.

Comment: Have you tried to use the `strict` option? https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#allow-redirects: _"strict: (bool, default=false) Set to true to use strict redirects. Strict RFC compliant redirects mean that POST redirect requests are sent as POST requests vs. doing what most browsers do which is redirect POST requests with GET requests."_ - I think the same should apply for HEAD requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up dealing with this myself with a little recursive function that re-issues HEAD requests on the redirects:

```
private function getHeaders(string $url): array
{
    $response = $this->guzzle->head($url, ['allow_redirects' => false]);

    // If the response is a redirect, follow it. Avoids Guzzle changing a HEAD request to a GET request after
    // following redirects.
    if (in_array($response->getStatusCode(), [301, 302, 307, 308])) {
        return $this->getHeaders($response->getHeader('Location')[0]);
    }

    return $response->getHeaders();
}
```